# Wix dll error when start 64 bit process

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I have this configuration for wxs

```
<CustomAction Id="UninstallDriver" BinaryKey="Setup.CustomActions.dll"
              DllEntry="UninstallDriver" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>
<Custom Action="UninstallDriver" After="InstallInitialize">Installed AND (NOT REINSTALL)</Custom>
```

And custom action:

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Uninstall driver
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="session"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult UninstallDriver(Session session)
    {
        try
        {
            session.Log("Start unistalling redirect driver");
            var toolPath = GetPathToFile(session, @"%INSTALLLOCATION%Tools.exe");
            session.Log("Path for tools={0}", toolPath);
            if (!File.Exists(toolPath))
            {
                session.Log("Can't find Tools.exe at specified location");
                return ActionResult.Failure;
            }
            var proc = Process.Start(toolPath);
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/uninstall";
            proc.Start();
            var exited = proc.WaitForExit(10000);
            if (exited && proc.ExitCode == 0)
            {
                session.Log("Driver uninstall completed");
                return ActionResult.Success;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            session.Log("Error while uninstalling driver={0}", ex.Message);
        }
        return ActionResult.Failure;
    }
```

And when it invoke this custom action on uninstalling i have "DLL required for this install to complete could not be run". But when i build Tools.exe for x86 no problems occuried. How to make it work with 64x bit version?

Comment: What version of WiX are you using? EDIT: Also, shouldn't uninstalling a driver be a `deferred` action?

Comment: version 3.6. Last version

Comment: Are you using Votive (WiX projects that are embedded in Visual Studio)?
The .dll you should be linking to should be named something like "CustomActions.CA.dll"

Comment: it is better not to delay) No, standalone i think

Comment: what is the `platform target` of the assembly which has the custom action? Also, I would agree with @Izzy custom action should be `deferred` because you'll need to run it with elevated permissions. You should test your installer with UAC turned on.

Comment: Tested on win7,win8,xp all works fine

Comment: I'd check your build configuration settings and ensure that the library is built when compiling for x64 (and that it's built before WiX tries to embed it into the installer).

Comment: Wow. I just solved my problem. Don't know what what really happened, but i have some unused custom actions and when i remove them from custom actions all start work. Thx for participation

Comment: Ahh, so it's possible they were referencing .dll's you had unlinked or dereferenced?

Comment: Do think so, references are not changed. It looks like wix compiler magic)

Comment: Lol, you might want to answer your own question then :)